Is todays T&G OSB compatible with older T&G planks?
I'm expanding a room in a 60s era home with T&G planks that are in good shape.  The groove of the older plank is accessible and looks ready to receive the tongue of the new OSB.
Will the T&G on newer OSB subfloor fit and work same as if im working with all new OSB?  I understand the T&G are designed to automatically set a proper gap between sheets.  Will it with older planks?
What issues will I run into regarding fit and finish?

If the thickness is exactly the same, then it should fit.  Sheets are close to actual size measurements.  Planks/lumber are sold by nominal size, the actual size has been shrinking over time.

Tongue and groove is used to stiffen the sheets/wood between the gaps between joists. Without the T&G each sheet would move(up/down) compared to the other sheet when walking on them between joists.  Thicker floor sheets/planks need it less than thinner sheets.

OP answer:  So I tested my modern T&G OSB against an old T&G subfloor plank pulled from the house.  In term of surface alignment (both top and bottom) the new board mate perfectly with the old plank.  No need for sanding or leveling.
Old board tongue does not work to set a auto-gap, but the new board's tongue does set a gap with the old plank groove, maybe slightly smaller than 1/8" but does keep a gap.



The new OSB may or may not be compatible with an 60 year old flooring plank.  This is a definite"hands on" test issue.  You will just need to fit it and see.
The manufacturing process can vary ever so slightly so there may need to be a slight trim with a router to make a smooth fit on the first row mating edge. Or you can cut off the tongue to get the first row to butt together.
The other issue is the thickness.  I have encountered thickness of materials being different between the same nominal size wood of different decades. OSB being the subfloor you may need to do some sanding at the mating edge with the old planks. If the difference is very minor, the finish flooring will take care of the issue depending on what that is.

Please do not make me older.  Have still close to twenty years to be 80.  Some of you young whipper snappers think we named our pets Dino.  We only watched the show, did not live then.

@crip, sorry...I fixed that...i should not have tried to do math before coffee.
